# Vba Error Handling / only int

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling, int

I would like to in the `Inputbox` only numbers are allowed and if someone types a letter Error Handling installed entry. The variable `zahl` I use later.

```
Dim inpt As Integer
Dim zahl As String
inpt = Application.InputBox("Date (YYMM)")
If inpt = False Then Exit Sub
MsgBox inpt
zahl = CInt(inpt)
```

Answer (score 3):

See the `InputBox` [MSDN Page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa195768(v=office.11).aspx).

Set the Type:=1

`inpt = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Date (YYMM)", Type:=1)`

This will force the user to enter a valid number before moving on.